# How many whole numbers $n$ have a difference $|\sqrt{n}-10| < 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, radicals

## Question

The difference of $\sqrt{n}$ and $10$ is less than $1$. How many whole numbers $n$ are there with this characteristic?
$$(A)\ 15 \ \ \ \ \ \ (B)\ 29 \ \ \ \ \ \ (C)\ 39  \ \ \ \ \ \ (D)\ 24 \ \ \ \ \ \ (E)\ 26 $$

### What I Am Stuck On:

First, know that whole numbers do not include negative or imaginary numbers, and zero is inside this category. I infer that this problem means that the difference could be negative, so the numbers that satisfy this condition are from $120$ to $0$ inclusive. So there are $120-0+1=121$ whole numbers. What went wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt[2]{n}$ is an unusual way to write a square root.  Are you sure it wasn't some other exponent?

Comment: You don't just need $\sqrt{n} - 10 \le 1$, you need $10 - \sqrt{n} \le 1$ as well.

Comment: @sbares I believe your interpretation is basically correct, but one minor point is that the question says that the difference is "less than $1$", so it should be $\sqrt{n}-10 \lt 1$ and $10 - \sqrt{n} \lt 1$ instead.

Comment: The numbers are from 120 to ...? (not 0, since $10-\sqrt{0}>1$).

Comment: In the title you're asking about $n-\sqrt{10}\le1$, and the beginning of the body sounds like $|n-\sqrt{10}|\le1$.

Comment: Right.  "The difference of $a$ and $b$" is not $a-b$.  It is $\max(a,b)-\min(a,b)$ or in other words $|a-b|$.  If $n <100$ then the difference of $\sqrt{n}$ and $10$ is not $\sqrt{n}- 10$ but is instead is $10 -\sqrt{n} $. So if $n<100$ so have $10-\sqrt{n}< 1$ or $9 < \sqrt{n}$ and $n> 81$.  (Also note the question is *strictly* less; not equal or less)..... and by example if $n=25$ say then the difference of $\sqrt{25}$ and $10$ is not $\sqrt{25}-10=5-10=-5< 1$.  It is $10-\sqrt{5}=10-5 = 5 > 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We suppose  $\sqrt n=r$. Then,  $|r−10|<1$  is the mathematical formulation of above statement. We thus get $9<\sqrt n=r<11$. Since all three sides of this inequality deal with positive numbers; we can square. So

$$81<n<121$$

Positive integers satisfying it are $\{82,83,84,\ldots,120\}$.

That is  $9+10+10+10=39$  positive integers.